# Propel (PHP ORM), Basic usage returns NULL for all (not empty) tables and columns

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I am using Propel ORM and I set everything that must be from Propel Documentation. I have tables and when i echo the result from some Table row the result is just NULL, and NULL for everything. 
Of course these tables/rows are not empty. It works fine with standart query.
The problem is that there are not errors, too and thats why i can't find the solution and I can'tt explain the problem, like I want. 
I am new with Propel and want to use it. Please, if there is someone with expirience to help me. 
I am using MySQL.
The code is just standart:

```
 // setup the autoloading
 require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

 // setup Propel
 require_once '../vendor/bin/generated-conf/config.php';

 $author = new Authors();

 echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($author);
 echo '</pre>';
```

The table is not empty.

Comment: You will need to post specific codes here.

Comment: sry, this is the code:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        `require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

       // setup Propel
       require_once '../vendor/bin/generated-conf/config.php';

       $author = new Authors();

       echo '<pre>';
       var_dump($author);
       echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/08-logging.html

You will more info about errors from logs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$author = new Authors();
```

Is not retrieving all of the rows in Authors (is the table named author or authors?). For that, you need to use a query:

```
$q = \AuthorsQuery::create();
$authors = $q->find();
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    var_dump($author->toArray());
}
```